# What is key64 data type supposed to represent?

Tags: borromean

In the codebase I saw `key64`, I am guessing it is 64 bytes array, but what is it meant to represent in genBorromean for example?

A point/number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typedef key key64[64];` [[ref]](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/6335509727661349e50c54c4e0eafd692f0d6907/src/ringct/rctTypes.h#L137)

So it's an array of 64 `key`'s.

And a `key` is a struct that holds 32 bytes [[ref]](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/6335509727661349e50c54c4e0eafd692f0d6907/src/ringct/rctTypes.h#L78).

Quoting the comment for the `key` struct:

```
// Can contain a secret or public key
```

Comment: Got it, it holds 32 * 64 bytes altogether. How will I know if it is private key or public key?

Comment: "How will I know if it is private key or public key?" <- it can hold either. Depends where it is used whether it's a public key or private key.

Comment: I mean is there a naming scheme for public key? I see sometimes it's capital letter. Maybe that means public key?

Comment: No. There is no naming scheme. It's a data type that can hold either a public or private key.

Comment: Also I saw " key64 K[2]" Does this mean we have 2 X 64 keys?

Comment: Got it, I thought that if the variable name begins with capital letter, then it means it is representing a public key as bytes

Comment: "Also I saw " key64 K[2]" Does this mean we have 2 X 64 keys?" <- 2 x 64 x 32

Comment: 2 x 64 x 32 bytes, but it represents 2 X 64 keys ? where a key is 32 bytes

Comment: "I thought that if the variable name begins with capital letter..." <- right, but you didn't ask about variable names, you asked about a data type. For variable names, yes, it appears in *some* of the code that public keys are capitalized, but I wouldn't take this as gospel. Many people have written code and they may use their own style/scheme.

Comment: "but it represents 2 X 64 keys ? where a key is 32 bytes" <- Yes. As I said, a key is 32 bytes, key64 is 64 keys so key64[2] is 2 x 64 x 32.